# Gerrit remote branch ownership

Tags: git, branch, gerrit

I have been using Gerrit for a while now however I could not figure out somthing about remote branches.

I would like to set Gerrit settings so each person that uses the repository may create a new remote branch in Gerrit and in addition, only that person will be granted owner permission to that specific branch.

With that for example, he will be able to force push only to that branch.

I hope this is possible and someone will be able to explain me how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `${username}` as variable in ACLs, see the sandbox examples [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#_project_access_control_lists).

This would allow you to provide defined refs/branches that contain special permissions for every user (e.g. `refs/heads/${username}/*` to allow branches in the form of `username/whatever`)

Comment: Let me see if i understand correctly. I edit a new reference in the project access page the following: refs/heads/$(username)/*                                      Then I add push permission for example however to which group ?

Comment: `${username}` (beware the curly braces!) is always replaced with the user name interacting with Gerrit. So you can specify that every user has access to his/her own "branch space" under and all other members of a certain group have, e.g., only ready access for that. Have you read about the _sandbox_ concept in the docs? That's very close to what you want. Replace `refs/sandbox/` with `refs/heads/` and it's not an obscure ref spec, but a normal branch.